# how to pass entire model from view to controller or Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

how do you pass an entire model from view to controller or a JavaScript function.

I have seen how to build the model pieces of the model in the view from textboxes, and then it posts back to the controller.

My question is if there is already a model that has been passed into the View.  What is the easiest way to get it out?  I don't need to change any of the models data in the view.  I just want to hand it back to the controller.

Comment: If you are not changing anything, it seems it would be faster to just send whatever key you used to generate the model and let the controller just remanufacture it as you already have all of that code in place somewhere.  Less HTTP load and less front-end/additional code.  If you really really want to just pass the values back to the controller, follow the same examples you have seen in other places, but use the `@Html.HiddenFor()` helper instead of Textboxes/Checkboxes/etc.  This will allow you to POST the values back but will not render anything visible to the UI.

Comment: As @Tommy implies, you really do not want to send unwanted data to the client. That is a waste of bandwidth and a potential security risk. You want to pass a unique key that represents the model and store that in the page as a `@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ID)`

Comment: Hmm. I see your points.  so I guess its faster and safer to just call the database again in my new controller method and regenerate the model?

Comment: @Farmer - in most scenarios, yes.  If it is some uber complicated model, then you may want to look at using Session/HttpCache but most models take literally no time to just regenerate to get the data that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your form, you can do this for the values you want to keep:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model = > model.valueIwant)
```

A new hidden input tag will be added to your page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="valueIwant" value="the value">
```

When you post to the server, the value will be bound back onto your model on the server side. You can do this for as many values as you like.

Comment: I was kinda hoping to avoid doing this 99 times.  or once for each value in my model.  I was hoping their was a HiddenFor model.ENTIREMODEL or something

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do something more in line with webforms than MVC. webforms maintains state across postbacks by saving ALL the data as a hidden field in the page. Using MVC, your controller should ideally create/get all the data needed for your view at each request. So I must agree with @Tommy too. You might be better off maintaining the ID of the data you want and retrieving it server side at each request. Otherwise webforms might be a good option for you.

Comment: Perhaps, putting the data in the session would be an option, rather than saving it in the markup of the page?